# PHP + ImageMagick ／ サーバにインストールされている全てのフォント毎に、ダミー文字列を一覧でテキスト画像化したい

Tags: php, imagemagick

**現状**
フォント名を含む一覧は取得できたのですが、これをループで回して画像出力するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

```
exec("convert -list font", $output);
print_r($output);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Path: /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.5.4/config/type-ghostscript.xml
    [2] =>   Font: AvantGarde-Book
    [3] =>     family: AvantGarde
    [4] =>     style: Normal
    [5] =>     stretch: Normal
    [6] =>     weight: 400
    [7] =>     glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/a010013l.pfb
    [8] =>   Font: AvantGarde-BookOblique
    [9] =>     family: AvantGarde
    [10] =>     style: Oblique
    [11] =>     stretch: Normal
    [12] =>     weight: 400
    [13] =>     glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/a010033l.pfb
    [14] =>   Font: AvantGarde-Demi
    [15] =>     family: AvantGarde
    [16] =>     style: Normal
    [17] =>     stretch: Normal
    [18] =>     weight: 600
    [19] =>     glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/a010015l.pfb
    [20] =>   Font: AvantGarde-DemiOblique
    [21] =>     family: AvantGarde
    [22] =>     style: Oblique
    [23] =>     stretch: Normal
    [24] =>     weight: 600
    [25] =>     glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/a010035l.pfb
    [26] =>   Font: Bookman-Demi
    [27] =>     family: Bookman
    [28] =>     style: Normal
    [29] =>     stretch: Normal
    [30] =>     weight: 600
    [31] =>     glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/b018015l.pfb
    [32] =>   Font: Bookman-DemiItalic
```

---

**環境**
・CentOS 6.4
・ImageMagick-6.5.4
・PHP 5.4.32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exec を使うのであればシェルスクリプト(one-liner)でも良いかと思います。

```
exec("convert -list font | grep -Po '(?<=Font: ).+' | xargs -I@ convert -background white -fill black -font '@' -pointsize 64 label:'StackOverFlow' 'output/@.png'")
```

`label:` に文字列を指定します。また、画像ファイルの出力先を `./output` ディレクトリにしていますが、実際には絶対パスで指定する方が良いかと思います(予めディレクトリを作成しておくのをお忘れなく)。

ただ、フォントの種類によっては変換できない(文字コードに対応するフォントグリフを持っていないか、別のグリフが割り当てられている)場合があって、その場合には俗に言う「豆腐」になったり、「文字化け」の様な状態になりますのでご留意下さい。

- Analecta
  [image: Analecta]
- Impact
  [image: Impact]
- mry_KacstQurn

[image: mry_KacstQurn]

- msam10

[image: msam10]

**追記**

exec() を使わないで同様の処理を行う場合、PHP のプログラムから ImageMagick のライブラリを利用することになるかと思います。Ubuntu Linux では `php5-imagick` パッケージがそれに当たります。まずはそのパッケージをインストールします。

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

コードとしては以下で、これは前述のシェルスクリプトと同じ処理を行います。

```
<?php

  function draw_text($text, $font, $size, $output_dir) {
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setFont($font);
    $draw->setFontSize($size);
    $draw->setFillColor('black');
    $draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);

    $bg = new ImagickPixel();
    $bg->setColor('white');

    $img = new Imagick();
    $metrics = $img->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);
    $img->newImage($metrics['textWidth'], $metrics['textHeight'], $bg);
    $img->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $text);

    $img->setImageFormat('png');
    $img->writeImage($output_dir . "/" . $font . '.png');

    $img->destroy();
  }

  $text = 'StackOverFlow';
  $size = 64;
  $output_dir = './output';

  $fonts = (new Imagick)->queryFonts();
  foreach($fonts as $font){
    draw_text($text, $font, $size, $output_dir);
  }
?>
```

PHP でプログラムを書くのは初めてなので、非効率的な書き方になっていると思いますが、参考にしてみて下さい。

Comment: 期待通り動作しました！ 動作したのですが、一点教えて下さい。exec を使用しない方法も可能なのでしょうか？ 質問した時点では、コマンドでlistを取得した後、Imagickでしか処理できないと思っていたので…。それとも、listを取得する段階から、コマンドを使用せずに全てをImagickだけで処理出来るのでしょうか？　コメント趣旨としては、execを使用しない方法があればそちらの方が良いので知りたい、です。

Comment: PHP から ImageMagick のライブラリを使う方法を追記しました。

Comment: 期待通り動作しました！
 ＞PHP でプログラムを書くのは初めてなので。
無茶振りしてすいません。大変参考になりました。